# How was the invisibility cloak actually made?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-items

Following the thought process in this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/invisible-cloak-overrated-much), it mentions that typical [invisibility cloaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_objects_in_Harry_Potter#Invisibility_Cloaks) (which lose their properties over time) are created with a Disillusionment charm.

How then, could [Harry's "perfect" invisibility cloak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_objects_in_Harry_Potter#Harry.27s_Cloak_of_Invisibility) be made?

Comment: Considering the tale of the Deathly Hallows it was cut from Death's own cloak. Considering the nature of Death where would anything of his/hers/its come from ?

Comment: @Xantec: I think that's the answer. Cite the book and make it so, friend!

Comment: This is blatantly answered in the 7th book. It's a huge plot point. I would suggest you read that.

Comment: Sorry, it has been some time in between reading the 7th book and watching the movie.  I didn't realize it was so blatantly obvious.  Though I do think it is a valid question and don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I down voted because if you watched the movie or read the book, it says when they read Beatle the Bard story of the 3 brothers how the three hallows were made.

Comment: I don't think it is so clearly answered, there is the kid's story, but I doubt that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Initially the reader is left to think that the story of the three brothers was true, and consequently the deathly hallows.  However, Hermione did mention that it was probably more likely that the three brothers were powerful wizards and forged the items themselves.

More likely than not, they discovered some sort of powerful magic which has since been lost.

Comment: Isn't it actually Dumbledore who mentions that in King's Cross?

Answer (score 1):

The cloak is part of the essence of death itself.  It inherits it powers from that much as a dragon has its powers to breathe fire from being a dragon.

Answer (score 0):

I have no source for what I am telling you. I am just asuming based on information from Potter Wiki, Pottermore and the famous book ''Fantastic beasts and where to find them''.

But as we know, the Peverell brothers were powerful magicians, so there is no doubt that magic is involved. Hermione is mentioning they may have forged the objects themselves.

My guess is that the cloaks who loses their invisibility is mostly made using  Disillusionment Charm or a Bedazzlement Hex, whilst the cloak Harry possesses is made out of Demiguise pelt. In FBWFT (Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them) it's stated that Demiguise pelt is used for Cloaks, but on the Potter Wiki it is added a sentence which makes me come to my later conclusion: Cloaks made from their hair eventually turn opaque, losing their invisibility effects as time passes.

What if Ignotus was a very skilled hunter, aswell as a tailor? Maybe he managed to weave the hair of a Demiguise in a sertain way and maybe he knew how to treat the pelt so it would never fade?